# Getting tag values with in the Tags from XML

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, xmldocument

I have below Xml file Content, I am trying to get values of `<text>` & `<content .. />` tag which are inside the tag `<navmap> ... </navmap>` only.

I am using `XmlDocument()` of nameSpace `using Windows.Data.Xml.Dom;`

I worked with `XmlDocument()` earlier, But this type of XMl content is quite different, I am not getting idea which property I have to use for Tag value with in the tag.

```
      <docTitle>
         <text>XXXXXXX</text>
      </docTitle>
  <navMap>
    <navPoint id="navpoint-1" playOrder="1">
      <navLabel>
        <text>Title Page</text>
      </navLabel>
        <content src="000.html" />
    </navPoint>
    <navPoint id="navpoint-2" playOrder="2">
      <navLabel>
        <text>Main Text</text>
      </navLabel>
        <content src="01M.html" />
    </navPoint>
  </navMap>
```

I am Working With Windows store apps using c#
I tried like this..

```
            using Windows.Data.Xml.Dom;
             ---------------
             ---------------
             ---------------

            StorageFile tocFile = await finalfolder.GetFileAsync(tocFileValue);
            string fileContents1 = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(tocFile);
            string encodedContent1 = fileContents1.Replace("&nbsp;", "&#160;");
            tocDocument.LoadXml(encodedContent1,loadSettings1);
            XmlNodeList tocNodeList = tocDocument.GetElementsByTagName("navMap");
            foreach (XmlElement Element in tocNodeList)
            {
                //Element is showing as null..
            }
```

Who are Familiar with `XmlDocument()` of nameSpace `using Windows.Data.Xml.Dom;` give me Suggestion.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Simply do this...

```
 XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(urXml);

    XmlNodeList textlist = xml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
    XmlNodeList contentList = xml.GetElementsByTagName("content");

    for (int i = 0; i < textlist.Count; i++)
    {
        string s1 = textlist[i].InnerText; //
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < contentList.Count; j++)
    {
        string s2 = contentList[j].InnerText;
    }
```

**U can get the text through this..string is taken just to show tht u can get the inner text..if you want to store all the values under text tag..use list and Add their innerText**

like:-

```
for (int i = 0; i < textlist.Count; i++)
{
if(i==0)
List<string> str=new list<string>();

str.Add(textlist[i].InnerText);
}
```

same the case with content tag..

Hope This Helps..:)

Comment: Have U seen `<text>` tag in `<doctitle>` tag before `<navmap>`..?

Comment: If You want all text tag value to add in a list u can have it by using this method..even if u have it in <doctitle> tag.TextList will contain an ordered collection of text Node and u can extract the inner text in ordered way through this method..

Comment: OK, How it make it as using `<navMap>`.
And one more thing, For `contentlist` the Innertext won't work, Because the sec value is with in the tag. I am doing like this `XmlAttribute Str1 = idref.GetAttributeNode("src");
Contentlist.Add(Str1.Value);`

Answer (score 1):

**With XmlDocument you could do the following...**

```
XmlNodeList xnList = xd.SelectNodes("navMap/navPoint"); //xd being your xmldocument.   returns all "navPoint" nodes under navMap and navMap  is your root node
        foreach (XmlNode node in xnList)
        {
            string retText = node["navLabel"]["text"].InnerText;                 // navLabel/text
            string retContentAtt = node["content"].Attributes["src"].Value;    // navPoint/content src=" 
        }
```

I think this is what you are looking for. Hope it helps

Comment: Getting Error `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Page.XmlNode'` On `node["navLabel"]["text"].`

Comment: What if you replace it with 
`string retText = node.SelectSingleNode("navLabel").SelectSingleNode("text").InnerText;
                
string retContentAtt = node.SelectSingleNode("content").Attributes["src"].Value;`

Comment: No It wont work,
Is it is `XmlDocument()` of nameSpace using Windows.Data.Xml.Dom;
[http://sdrv.ms/13lwh9Q ]

Comment: Unable to test. Reading from google results. Try...
`string retText = node.FirstChild.FirstChild.InnerText;                 
                XmlAttributeCollection attributes = node.LastChild.Attributes;
                string retContentAtt = attributes[0].Value;`

Comment: No,Sorry. It is looking same as what the Image I posted earlier.
I am going through another answer with some changes.
Thanks for your valuable solution